# How to make same words unique in a formula to peform math in a dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I need to replace strings in a mathematical Formula. The formula can take any form and reference the attribute name of a table. If that reference is repeated, it should only replace them one per record retrieved.

I was thinking to use a suffix, like in this example, I would replace:

```
@Formula = (Imports + Imports + Imports)
```

by:

```
@Formula = (Imports@1 + Imports@2 + Imports@3)....
```

Similarly, if the formula was `(Imports + exports + Imports)` it should be replaced by

```
@Formula = (Imports@1 + exports + Imports@2)
```

The purpose is that each `imports` value gets replaced by a different value. But when I use the dynamic SQL as shown below, I get the wrong answer: it replaces each `imports` with the same value after the first iteration, and the values of the 2 next iterations are left unused.

```
CREATE TABLE #MathLogicExecution 
(
    IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
    Expression VARCHAR(256)
)
WHILE @ig<=@INPUTCOUNT
BEGIN
    SELECT @ig =1
    INSERT INTO #MathLogicExecution 
        SELECT REPLACE(@FORMULA,ATTRIBUTENAME,INPUTVALUES)
            FROM  #MathLogicTable
            WHERE IDNUM = @ig
    SET @FORMULA = (Select Expression
                    from   #MathLogicExecution
                    where  IDNUM = @ig)
    SET @ig =@ig +1
END
```

When the variables are:

```
@INPUTCOUNT=3 , @FORMULA=(IMPORTS + IMPORTS + IMPORTS),
```

and `#MathlogicTable` has the below values:

```
             IDNUM    Attributename  Inputvalues
             ------------------------------------
              1         IMPORTS      45
              2         IMPORTS      23
              3         IMPORTS      28
```

then when I execute the above code I'm getting the output execution as `(45 +45+45) = 135`. But instead I want it to become `(45 + 23 + 28) = 96`

So in the above code I'm trying to replace the `@Formula` progressively with the integer values retrieved from my table, so that I can perform the math in dynamic SQL...

How can I make this work?

Comment: Please try to describe in other words what you are trying to achieve. I do not understand this... Please provide sample data and expected output, best would be a [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: can u show how the variables changed after passed it into dynamic sql?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments.. I modified the code as per the comments.. please check and let me know if you need any further information ?

Comment: I still have no idea what you're actually trying to achieve.  I don't understand why you're using dynamic SQL at all, and I don't understand why you're using a loop to stage a temp table to use for dynamic SQL.  It looks to me like, instead of using set-based operations, you're treating SQL as a procedural language.  It looks like you're jumping through tremendous hoops to do very simple tasks.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your question now. In the SQL you have `@ig` set to 1 and it never changes (unless I am mistaken). So I don't see how you can expect it to return anything about `idnum` 2 and 3 from the data you listed. Could you explain and/or correct your question?

Comment: @bacon- This is a part of a code from 160 line Stored Procedure... where I'm stuck... I hope you understand...

Comment: @trincot - Yes i missed few code part while pasting it in the site the loops are incrementing but still the issue persist.. I have done the changes.. let me know if you need any further modifications in the question ?

Comment: Ok, I rewrote several phrases in your question, and voted for reopening it. Please review the question to see that it reflects what you want. Note that you should leave open how the matter is resolved. Adding `@1` might not be what you will get as the best  working solution. So better not stress that too much.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.. :)